# Lenient date parsing for syslog messages

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to parse the following date: `May  5 18:44:44` from a syslog entry. Note that after 'May' there are *2* spaces: one as separator and the other as omitted zero from the day of month.

The following code fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "May  5 18:44:44" is malformed at " 5 18:44:44"`

```
String input = "May  5 18:44:44";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM d HH:mm:ss")
    .withLocale(Locale.US);
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(input);
```

Apparently the parser does not grok the 2nd space. And it also works when I "manually" remove that 2nd space.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this either with joda time or standard java `DateFormat`?

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much a duplicate. Searched quite a while to not find it ...

Comment: Regular Expressions are a good method to burn CPU cycles, but if you are willing you can use grok. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565755/how-to-parse-using-grok-from-java-is-there-any-example-available

Answer (score 1):

Would you be willing to run `'s/\s+/ '` first?

Comment: While I was hoping that there is a magic letter in the format or setting for the formatter, I think this a very good solution here. Thanks.