# How to match files with content formatted by log 4j conversion pattern

Tags: java, regex, log4j

My program reads files and if the file is formatted using the user provided log4j conversion pattern (log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern)

Basically I need to convert log4j conversion pattern to corresponding java regex dynamically and check file content pattern.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28482881/4607733) helpful?

Comment: Thanks horcrux... The link u shared was asking same question. But i am not allowed to use any such third party tools or libraries because of existing framework. Is there any log4j function which can identify file format pattern?